# Qual é a diferença entre new Function e eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

Qual é a diferença entre `new Function` e `eval`, já que os dois parecem fazer a mesma coisa?

Exemplo com `eval`:

```
eval('1 + 1'); // 2
```

Exemplo com `new Function`:

```
new Function('', 'return (1+1)')() // 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### eval

> O método eval() avalia código JavaScript representado como uma string. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

#### Function

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript every function is actually a Function object. – [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Tradução livre:

> O construtor `Function` cria um novo objeto de função anonima. No Javascript todas as funções atualmente são um objeto de função.

---

A documentação se auto-explica, basicamente o **eval** executa uma expressão, *statement* e etc. Já o construtor **Function** cria um novo objeto de função com direito a todo o seu *prototype*.

#### Exemplos:

```js
var a = new Function('', 'return (1+1)');
var b = eval("2 + a()");
var c = b + a();
var d = new Function("p", "return a() + b + c + p");
var e = eval("d(10) - 20");

console.log(a())   // 2
console.log(b)     // 4
console.log(c)     // 6
console.log(d(10)) // 22
console.log(e);    // 2
```

No site do [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) possui esse exemplo na sessão do construtor `Function`:

```
var myFunction = new Function("a", "b", "return a * b");
var x = myFunction(4, 3);
```

E logo após diz o seguinte seguido de outro exemplo:

> You actually don't have to use the function constructor. The example above is the same as writing:
>
> ```
> var myFunction = function (a, b) {return a * b};
> var x = myFunction(4, 3);
> ```

A frase diz o seguinte (tradução livre):

> Atualmente você não precisa usar o construtor de funções. O exemplo abaixo tem o mesmo efeito.

Comment: O `undescore.js` usa o `new Function` :) na criação de templates

Comment: Bacana @WallaceMaxters, na verdade acho que eu nunca tinha visto o `new Function`. Sou novo com Javascript, não é do meu tempo... kkkkk

Answer (score 7):

Elas não fazem a mesma coisa:

`eval()` avalia uma string como uma expressão JavaScript dentro do escopo atual e pode acessar variáveis locais.

`new Function` parseia o código para um objeto de função, que pode ser chamado. Ele não pode acessar as variáveis locais, porque o código é executado em um escopo separado.

O que isso quer dizer? Rode esse código:

```js
function testEval() {
    var a = 'original';
    eval("(a = 'alterado')");
    console.log(a);
}

function testNewFunction() {
    var a = 'original';
    new Function("(a = 'alterado')")();
    console.log(a);
}

testEval()
testNewFunction()
```

Quando usamos `eval` o valor da variável `a` é alterado. Quando usamos `new Function` ela permanece inalterado.

Comment: Acho que você se enganou quanto ao escopo de variáveis, pode dar um exemplo onde o `Function` não acessa as variáveis que o `eval` consegue?

Comment: A grande diferença é essa de escopo mesmo.

Comment: @bfavaretto a grande diferença é que `Function` retorna uma função, e `eval` não pode retornar uma função, retorna o resultado de uma expressão.

Comment: Sim @KaduAmaral, mas `Function` é muito mais útil (e mais usado) pra criar um `eval` global do que para criar instâncias de função a serem usadas mais tarde.