# Calcular integral modo trapézio

Tags: javascript, matemática

Eu preciso calcular integral com o método trapézio. Acredito que o erro pode ser no `for`. Os havia testado passo a passo e funcionou.

```
    function integratrapezio(){         
    var elmbasea = document.getElementById("valoresdex").value;
    var elemb = document.getElementById("valoresdey").value;
    var elemquant = document.getElementById("valoresden").value;
    var elemfuncao = document.getElementById("valordafuncao").value;

    var k = (elmbasea-elemb)/elemquant;

    var n = +elemquant+1;   
    var elemk = +k/2;

    var f = "x+2";

    var cont = 0;

    for (j=1;j<n; j++){

        var i=+j-1;
                if ((i == 0)){c=1;}else{c=2;}
                var x=+elmbasea+i*+k;   

                var funcao = eval(elemfuncao);

                var calculodafuncao=cont+c*funcao;
                var cont = calculodafuncao;

        alert(calculodafuncao);             

    }



    var total=+elemk*+calculodafuncao;

    /*qualcular a função f = (x)       https://www1.univap.br/spilling/CN/CN_Capt6.pdf*/                
    if(document.getElementById('resultFunc').style.visibility = 'Visible'){document.getElementById('resultFunc').style.visibility = 'hidden';}

    if(document.getElementById('resultFunc').style.visibility = 'hidden'){document.getElementById('resultFunc').style.visibility = 'visible';}

    document.getElementById('resultFunc').innerHTML = total;

}
```

Comment: Bem vindo. Qual é o seu problema? Pode explicar melhor o que não funciona no código?

Comment: Dica: Em JavaScript e em outras linguagens descendentes do C, não confunda `=` com `==`.

Comment: Ao invés de postar respostas que não respondem a pergunta, edite a pergunta. Já coloquei o conteúdo do que você postou como resposta aqui, mas fica a dica para a próxima vez.

Comment: O PDF da função que você quer "*qualcular*" não abre para mim.

Comment: Victor, nao entendi direito sua resposta.

Comment: Leonardo, não sei ainda o que nao funciona, mas deve ser no for......

Comment: Seus dois códigos têm um monte de erros. Mas não entendi que processo de cálculo você está tentando usar. O problema é que quando você faz `if (c = 0)` você não está **verificando** se `c` é zero, está **tornando-o** zero. O que você queria é `if (c == 0)`. No entanto, ainda tem vários outros erros, tal como tentar usar uma variável antes dela ter sido declarada ou inicializada.

Comment: Valew, essa daqui "if (c = 0) " ja tinha alterado. quanto, "uma variável antes dela ter sido declarada ou inicializada."  pode me ajudar..

Comment: Eu sinceramente recomendo o uso de uma biblioteca externa para executar tarefas assim complexas, como por exemplo a biblioteca http://mathjs.org

Answer (score 7):

Particularmente eu achei muito esquisito o que você fez para calcular a integral no modo dos trapézios. Não tem muitos segredos ao fazer a integral com esse método. A única coisa questionável é se você define o tamanho dos trapézios ou em quantos trapézios divide o intervalo. A seguir um exemplo definindo o tamanho de cada trapézio:

```js
function trapezio(lbda, ini, fim, delta) {
  let integral = 0.0;
  let last_lbda = lbda(ini);
  for (let i = ini + delta; i <= fim; i += delta) {
    let now_lbda = lbda(i);
    integral += delta*(now_lbda+last_lbda)/2;
    last_lbda = now_lbda;
  }
  return integral;
}

function info_trapezio_quadrado(ini, fim, delta) {
  let result = trapezio((i) => i*i, ini, fim, delta);
  console.log("função quadrada, de " + ini + " a " + fim +", delta = " + delta);
  console.log(">integral = " + result);
}

info_trapezio_quadrado(0, 2, 1);
info_trapezio_quadrado(0, 2, 0.5);
info_trapezio_quadrado(0, 2, 0.1);
info_trapezio_quadrado(0, 2, 0.01);
info_trapezio_quadrado(0, 2, 0.001);
```

Explicando o código:

- os argumentos são uma função qualquer dos reais nos reais `lbda`, o intervalo `[ini, fim)` e o tamanho da base dos trapézios `delta`
- o cálculo da área de um trapézio retângulo é `base * (altura1 + altura2)/2`
- a integral é o somatório da área de todos os trapézios, começando em `ini` e terminando em `fim`

Uma versão que faz menos operações, porém menos legível, é:

```js
function trapezio_menos_operacoes(lbda, ini, fim, delta) {
  let lbda_ini = lbda(ini);
  let somas = lbda_ini;
  let last_lbda = lbda_ini;
  for (let i = ini + delta; i <= fim; i += delta) {
    last_lbda = lbda(i)
    somas += last_lbda;
  }
  let integral = delta*(somas - (lbda_ini + last_lbda)/2.0);
  return integral;
}
```

Nessa versão, estou me valendo de que cada altura dos trapézios é levada em conta duas vezes na versão original (exceto o primeiro e o último). Por exemplo, para a função quadrada com delta = 0.5 (integrando de 0 a 2):

```
iteração | i    | f(i) | área do trapézio              | área acumulada
---------+------+------+-------------------------------+----------------
0        | 0    | 0    | 0                             | 0
1        | 0.50 | 0.25 | 0.5*(0.00 + 0.25)/2 = 0.0625  | 0.0625
2        | 1.00 | 1.00 | 0.5*(0.25 + 1.00)/2 = 0.3125  | 0.3750
3        | 1.50 | 2.25 | 0.5*(1.00 + 2.25)/2 = 0.8125  | 1.1875
4        | 2.00 | 4.00 | 0.5*(2.25 + 4.00)/2 = 1.5625  | 2.7500
```

Notou como valor de `f(0.5)` se repetiu em dois momentos? Na área do trapézio da iteração 1 e na iteração 2? E que o mesmo aconteceu para `f(1.0)` (iterações 2 e 3) e `f(1.5)` (iterações 3 e 4)? Se eu fizesse as somas na mão seria algo assim:

```
delta*(f(0.0) + f(0.5))/2 + [primeiro trapézio]
delta*(f(0.5) + f(1.0))/2 + [segundo trapézio]
delta*(f(1.0) + f(1.5))/2 + [terceiro trapézio]
delta*(f(1.5) + f(2.0))/2   [quarto trapézio]
-------------------------
delta/2 * (
  f(0.0) +
  f(0.5) + f(0.5) +
  f(1.0) + f(1.0) +
  f(1.5) + f(1.5) +
  f(2.0)
)
```

O resto foram truques matemáticos para minimizar a quantidade de operações.

---

Aparentemente, você deseja pegar a fórmula de algum lugar, certo? Bem, podemos pegar do input, a variável sendo `x`:

```js
function faz_leitura(form) {
  let ini = Number(document.getElementById("ini").value);
  let fim = Number(document.getElementById("fim").value);
  let delta = Number(document.getElementById("delta").value);
  let equacao = document.getElementById("equacao").value;
  
  let pre_lambda = "(x) => " + equacao;
  let lbda = eval(pre_lambda);
  
  let result = trapezio_menos_operacoes(lbda, ini, fim, delta);
  document.write("<div>Integral de " + ini + " até " + fim + " (delta " + delta + "), para a função " + pre_lambda + ": " + result + "</div>");
}

function trapezio_menos_operacoes(lbda, ini, fim, delta) {
  let lbda_ini = lbda(ini);
  let somas = lbda_ini;
  let last_lbda = lbda_ini;
  for (let i = ini + delta; i <= fim; i += delta) {
    last_lbda = lbda(i)
    somas += last_lbda;
  }
  let integral = delta*(somas - (lbda_ini + last_lbda)/2.0);
  return integral;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="faz_leitura(this); return false;">
<div>
  <input required type="text" id="equacao"/>
  <label>equação (use 'x' minúsculo para a variável)</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input required type="text" id="ini"/>
  <label>ini</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input required type="text" id="fim"/>
  <label>fim (deve ser maior que ini)</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input required type="text" id="delta">
  <label>delta (deve ser positivo)</label>
</div>
<button type="submit">Integral</button>
</form>
```

Notou que aqui eu separei a preocupação de cada função? Tem a função que trata da submissão do formulário, preenchendo as variáveis (`faz_leitura`) e a função que realmente faz o cálculo da integral na estratégia dos trapézios (`trapezio_menos_operacoes`). A minha separação não ficou boa, não sou o mais experiente em JavaScript + HTML, mas já separa a lógica de negócio da interface.

> Olhando [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279988/64969), me deparo com o possível uso malicioso do `eval()`. Então, [evite o `eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/64969), é mais fácil. Vou editar essa questão para [usar  o `new Function()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77296/64969), mas agora estou sem condições de testar.

Referências:

- [classe `Number`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134455/64969)
- [sobre o botão de submissão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12289/64969)

<sup>Agradecimentos especiais aos seguintes usuários por me ajudarem a elaborar a resposta:
 [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss),
[@Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132/victor-stafusa),
[@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray), [@pss1suporte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6789/pss1suporte)</sup>

### Observações sobre as diferenças entre os dois somatórios

Sobre as duas versões da função de integração, matematicamente elas são iguais, considerando aritmética dos números reais e dos números racionais. Porém, números de ponto flutuante obedecem outras regras.

Quando se faz uma soma em ponto flutuante, você pode perder precisão. Isso é natural e às vezes até mesmo desejável. Eu discorro mais sobre o assunto em um dos pontos [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272376/64969).

A abordagem de não multiplicar pela base do trapézio faz com que os números sejam maiores, já que no ideal esse valor deve se aproximar de zero. Assim sendo, possivelmente o valor da função pode ser insignificante perante o total acumulado.

Outro ponto para se chamar a atenção é que, se o valor de `lbda(x)` for decrescente (mesmo que o decrescimento for ficando cada vez menor) conforme `x` se aproxima do limite final, o valor da somatória não irá se alterar. Isso seria apenas postergado se fosse feita a multiplicação pelo valor da base.

Uma possível medida para evitar isso seria acumular os números enquanto eles forem totalmente significativos em relação à somatória. Quando houver detecção de que o número somado terá parte da precisão perdida, ele deveria iniciar uma nova somatória é assim por diante. No final, dever-se-ia ordenar do menor para o maior e somar nessa ordem. Essa seria uma das maneiras de garantir ao máximo a precisão dos cálculos usando ponto flutuante.