# Como ativar uma função por um atributo?

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine um código:

```
<div id='teste' data-conteudo="funcao()"></div>
```

Quero que ao pegar o atributo `data-conteudo` a função "função()" seja acionada, como se fosse um valor do atributo "onclick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function funcao()
{
  alert("Dolly guaraná");
}

var dc = document.getElementById("teste").getAttribute("data-conteudo");

eval(dc);
```

```html
<div id='teste' data-conteudo="funcao()"></div>
```

### XSS

Créditos a [Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado) por me lembrar

---

Se um usuário mau intencionado entrar no seu site e fizer isso

```js
function pegar_todos_os_usuarios(){
 return [
   {name:"zé ramalho", pass:"ramalho"},
   {name:"Largato",    pass:"mosca"}
 ];
}
function funcao()
{
  alert("Dolly guaraná");
}

var dc = document.getElementById("teste").getAttribute("data-conteudo");

eval(dc);
```

```html
<div id='teste' data-conteudo="alert(JSON.stringify(pegar_todos_os_usuarios(), null, 4))"></div>
```

Agora imagine a bagunça que ele pode fazer

**Resumindo**

[Evite `eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/64969)

### Como evitar

Como isso é uma string, a cada função chamada, você poderá verificar se é aquilo mesmo que você quer, ex:

```js
function pegar_todos_os_usuarios(){
 return [
   {name:"zé ramalho", pass:"ramalho"},
   {name:"Largato",    pass:"mosca"}
 ];
}
function funcao()
{
  alert("Dolly guaraná");
}

var btn = document.querySelector(".opa");

btn.onclick = function () {
  var dc = document.getElementById("teste").getAttribute("data-conteudo");

  if (dc === 'funcao()') {
    eval(dc);
  } else {
    alert("Falha");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="teste" data-conteudo="pegar_todos_os_usuarios()"></div>

<button class="opa">EXECUTAR</button>
```

Comment: teria aceitado se o tempo deixa-se xD muito obrigado cara

Comment: @Raptador vem amanhã e aceita ;-)

Comment: @MarceloRafael, só lembrando que o `eval` é uma arma poderosa que não liga se vai ser usada para o bem ou para o mal, simplesmente usará tudo que tem lá. Normalmente é perigoso usar ele sem maiores cuidados

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado  verdade, esqueci do XSS, mas está aí né :)

Comment: Só deixando o alerta para o futuro leitor. Eu mesmo recentemente tive de usar `eval` vindo do input do usuário numa resposta.

Comment: Adorei o exemplo do ataque!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado valeu por lembrar, créditos pra vc cara, vlw.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de acrescentar um link relacionado ao "evite o eval()"

Answer (score 3):

Eu não usaria `eval` por motivos de segurança. Em vez disso criaria uma nova função que chamaria a função `funcao()` usando `new Function(nome_da_função())`:

```js
function funcao(){
   console.log("função executada");
}

var atr = document.getElementById("teste").dataset.conteudo;
var funcao2 = new Function(atr);
funcao2(); // outro nome que chama funcao()
funcao(); // nome original
```

```html
<div id='teste' data-conteudo="funcao()"></div>
```

Somente aconteceria que a `funcao()` passaria a ter um outro nome: `funcao2()`, sem deixar também de ser `funcao()`.

Comment: Não conhecia esse objeto `Function`

Comment: Pois é rrsss... é a vida nos ensinando :))