# Sendo H = 1 + ½ +1/3 + ¼ + ... + 1/N, faça um algoritmo para calcular H, sendo que N é digitado pelo usuário

Tags: java

O programa tá printando apenas 1, é como se ele não guardasse o valor da variável h, alguém pode ajudar? Segue o código:

```
public class MainUmSobreH {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double h = 0;
    int n = 4;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {

        h = h + 1/i;

        System.out.println(h);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necessário converter em **double** ao fazer a adição/divisão:

```
public class MainUmSobreH {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      double h = 0;
      int n = 4;
      for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {

        h = h + (double)1/i;

        System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

Assim deve funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Agora funcionou, mas poderia explicar o porque disso?

Comment: Porque do jeito que estava sendo feito antes, ambos os números (tanto o 1 fixo, como o "i" do for) eram definidos como inteiros, logo a divisão sempre dava um número inteiro arredondando. Por exemplo, 1/2 não dava 0.5 e sim 0

Comment: Outra solução simples é `1d/i`.

Comment: Em casos extremos, a resposta pode acabar gerando um possível erro de precisão. Não sei se esse erro será sensível com o formato de ponto flutuante de precisão dupla, mas existe a possibilidade disso acontecer

Answer (score 9):

Números de ponto flutuante são bestas mitológicas de comportamento errante. Ou pelo menos são assim caso você não saiba domá-los antes de usá-los.

Usando pontos flutuantes, eu posso somar 3 números em uma ordem e obter um resultado distinto do que somar esses mesmos números em outra ordem:

```
a + b + c =?= c + a + b
```

Eu discorro brevemente sobre o assunto em algumas respostas:

- [nessa aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279410/64969), eu tenho de fazer um somatório `f(n)*b` para diversos valores de `n`; uma das estratégias eu não coloquei o `b` em evidência, então a soma era `sum = f(1)*b + f(2)*b + f(3)*b`, com 3 multiplicações e 2 somas, já na outra alternativa eu só multiplico no final da soma `sum = b*(f(1) + f(2) + f(3))` com 2 somas e 1 multiplicação; e, não, não são somas equivalentes ao se levar em conta a precisão do ponto flutuante
- [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272376/64969), eu usei esse fato da perda de precisão como condição de parada em uma soma infinita, inclusive eu mostro que há casos em que somar `a + y == a, y != 0`, portanto `(a + y) + y == a`, mas que pode existir `a + (y + y) > a`

Então qual seria a forma de tentar garantir o máximo de precisão possível na soma? Somando do valor menos significante até o mais significante! Basicamente alterar a ordem do `for` [proposto pelo @Paulo R. F. Amorim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285951/64969). Também é possível fazer isso na recursão [proposto pelo @Marcos Andrade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285967/64969) com um pouco mais de cautela.

### Solução com iteração

```
double sum = 0d;
int n = 4
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    sum += 1d/i;
}
```

Estou usando a notação indicando que o número é um `double` conforme [proposto pelo @Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285945/sendo-h-1-%c2%bd-1-3-%c2%bc-1-n-fa%c3%a7a-um-algoritmo-para-calcular-h-sendo-q/285951#comment582548_285951). Outra alternativa seria fazendo `1.0/i`, que força o número a ser interpretado como `double` de qualquer sorte.

### Solução recursiva 1

A ideia aqui é ter uma função de interface que chama a função recursiva propriamente dita. Vamos passar, na função recursiva, a soma acumulada até então, assim poderemos ficar somando os menores elementos primeiros para do então somar o elemento mais significativo.

Essa estratégia lembra um pouco algumas soluções usadas em [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) quando não se deseja que quem vá consultar na base de dados precise saber que a lista a ser passada como um terceiro argumento não intuitivo precisa ser uma lista vazia.

```
public static double somaInverso(int n) {
    return somaInversoPrivado(n, 0.0);
}

private static double somaInversoPrivado(int n, double acumulado) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return 1.0 + acumulado;
  }
  return somaInversoPrivado(n-1, 1.0/n + acumulado);
}
```

Note que aqui eu deixei o método `somaInversoPrivado` como um método privado à classe que faz esses cálculo. É uma função auxiliar cuja [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17552/64969) não deve ser exposta.

### Solução recursiva 2

Aqui as coisas acontecem de modo semelhante à outra, mas no lugar de enviar a soma acumulada, eu envio em qual passo na recursão estou. Tenho de parar quando estou no passo `n`. A ideia é que o resultado do passo `i` é `1.0/i + sum(i+1, n)`, isso garante que no último passo recursivo seja retornado o menor valor, que será então somado com o segundo menor valor e assim por diante.

```
public static double somaInverso(int n) {
    return somaInversoPrivado(1, n);
}

private static double somaInversoPrivado(int i, int n) {
  if (n == i) {
    return 1.0/i;
  }
  return 1.0/i + somaInversoPrivado(i + 1, n);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Esse algoritmo também é um clássico exemplo de recursividade. Acho interessante deixar aqui como uma forma alternativa de finalizar o exemplo.

Simplificando o algoritmo (sem verificar por exceções etc):

```
package recursividade;

public class Progressao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double inicial = 0;
        int limite = 4;
        double resultado = inicial + CalcularProgressao(limite);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }

    public static double CalcularProgressao(int limite) {
        if (limite == 1) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        else {
            return 1.0/limite + CalcularProgressao(limite-1);
        }
    }
}
```

É importante citar que o return utiliza 1.0 ao invés de 1, já que é necessário retornar um Double.

Answer (score -3):

solução correta

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {

     double h = 0;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     double n = sc.nextDouble();

     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     //TODO: Calcule o valor de H de forma que resulte na soma dos termos
           
           h = h + (double)1/i;
          
      }
     //TODO: Imprima a soma dos termos, considerando um resultado com duas casas decimais:
        System.out.println(Math.round(h));
   }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).